# Flutter Record Sound Coming from Mic and Speaker

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

I want to record the sound coming from the Mic and Speaker. For this, I have used this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/record). but the problem is this only records the sound coming from mic, not the sound coming from speaker.

I want to achieve this for:
I am developing an flutter app where users can call each other (audio call only) using [agora rtc engine](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine). And they can record their conversation locally. I know agora has cloud recording but I want to store the recording locally.

Please let me know if there is any other plugin that records the internal audio (Speaker sound and mic sound at the same time) or if I am doing anything wrong.

My code for recording:

```
var recorder = Record();
await recorder.start(
  path: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/Test/recording.m4a',
  encoder: AudioEncoder.aacLc,
  bitRate: 128000,
  samplingRate: 44100,
)
```

Comment: I have same issue, did you get an work around? Cloud recording isn't good enough because it is producing pre-defined grid layout of the recorded video. I wanted the recording to show full  screen as it is during the call. I am also using Flutter 3 and Agora rtc engine